# Add Solus OS to Ubuntu grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi

After installing Solus OS in dual (in fact multi)-boot along Windows 10 and Kubuntu 20.04 the laptop shows at boot the boot menu created by Grub Customizer in Kubuntu (which I like) but without the last installed system (Solus). Updating grub doesn't add Solus, neither does any action in Grub Customizer.

I can add only an option called by default "*UEFI Firmware Settings*" which is a link to the *BIOS Startup Menu*. Solus can be booted there by selecting *Boot Menu > UEFI Linux Boot Loader*.

(That can be accessed with `Esc` for BIOS Startup Menu, as said [here](https://discuss.getsol.us/d/4097-ubuntu-grub-menu-entry-for-installed-solus-os-in-efi-mode)).

But can Solus be added to the Kubuntu grub list - I mean from Kubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible, if [this answer](https://discuss.getsol.us/d/3438-solus-installation-with-multiboot-is-not-working/4) is correct, saying:

> You most likely have Solus installed while the bios was set to UEFI
> mode. This will install Solus with the clr-boot-manager bootloader and
> not grub. Hence there are no grub entries created and hence Mint Grub
> will not have the entries available to boot. Reinstall Solus while the
> BIOS is set to 'BIOS Legacy' to install Solus with grub boot entries.
>
> The fact that the entry is located in loader/entries and the file
> extension is conf shows that it is not a grub entry. Grub uses .csv
> files in the same folder as the .efi.
> ...

> ... Consider using the BIOS itself to choose an OS to load (and the bootloader for which version,
> LTS or current, to boot) instead of one single bootloader for
> everything. In my experience that will save a lot of trouble when
> messing around.

From later experience I can say that, after restoring Ubuntu grub, this was able to see other Linux systems that don't use grub either (e.g. KaOS, which uses `systemd-grub`; installed after Ubuntu, it imposed its own boot menu which was [lacking an Ubuntu entry](https://forum.kaosx.us/d/2859-add-all-systems-to-boot-list), thus hiding the Ubuntu grub list under Firmware Interface/BIOS settings).

I'll mark this as this answer for Solus, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. I've done last week adding solus 4.3, on UEFI mode, to kubuntu 22.04 grub menu. I am doing a video with the steps.

English it's not my native language. It's easier to show on the video. For short, i edited an existing entry in grub with solus parameters.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiLoVgMeS0Q

```
menuentry 'Solus 4.3 Fortitude' --class solus --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-E7D4-2861' {
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root E7D4-2861
linux   /EFI/com.solus-project/kernel-com.solus-project.current.5.15.61-217 root=PARTUUID=7baeb13a-7de9-480d-ae68-3b84990aa33b quiet loglevel=3 splash systemd.show_status=false rw radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 resume=UUID=a45fa7fb-1f43-41d3-bc48-decaf50b613a
initrd /EFI/com.solus-project/initrd-com.solus-project.current.5.15.61-217
```

}

Comment: Could you put the steps in your answer? Thank you.

Comment: The video would be useful but not really needed here, the main steps would be great - in writing.